# Getting Item width in GridLayoutView

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am using a GridLayoutView, and I am adding Images to it. I want there to be 3 columns and spacing between the items. So far, everything is working, but when adding the images, I want to get the width of the Item. I could use `parent.getWidth() / 3` but I need the spacing to be calculated into the width of an Item. Is there an easy way to get the inner size of each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the ImageView's [onMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onMeasure(int,%20int)) method to obtain the width and height of the view:

```
onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
}
```

[More](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws) on the rendering procedure.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005245/how-to-have-a-gridview-that-adapts-its-height-when-items-are-added) may be useful to you as well.